# How can I dynamically set the TransactionTimeout for a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq, transactionscope, netmsmqbinding

I have a requirement to be able to dynamically set the transaction timeout for a WCF service running over MSMQ. I am following the example on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.channeldispatcher.transactiontimeout.aspx. However, the timeout that I am setting does not seem to be working.

The code that I am using to set the **TransactionTimeout** property is below:

```
ServiceProperties properties = ...; // has a TransactionTimeout value for the service
var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(...);
serviceHost.Open();
var channelDispatchers =
    serviceHost.ChannelDispatchers.Select(
        cd => new ChannelDispatcher(cd.Listener)).ToArray();
foreach (var channelDispatcher in channelDispatchers)
{
    channelDispatcher.TransactionTimeout = properties.TransactionTimeout;
}
```

When I run my service and put a 2-minute delay in my service implementation, I receive a transaction enlistment error when I try to write to another MSMQ queue:

> Exception: An error occurred while sending to the queue: The
>   transaction specified cannot be enlisted. (-1072824232,
>   0xc00e0058).Ensure that MSMQ is installed and running. If you are
>   sending to a local queue, ensure the queue exists with the required
>   access mode and authorization.

Has anyone been able to get this to work in the past? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First thoughts: Check that the MSMQ and MS DTC services are running on ALL participating systems; Also check the access priviledges on the queue(s) that the users that your services are running with have the required read/ write priviledges.

Comment: Everything is running locally. Permissions are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the right approach. The correct way to do this is to find and modify the ServiceBehaviorAttribute object that is attached to the service description:

```
var transactionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(...);
var behavior = serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();
behavior.TransactionTimeout = transactionTimeout.ToString();
serviceHost.Open();
```